# Multiple File handling C++, Variable scoring issue

Tags: c++, file-handling

**

## [Project Description PICTURE] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVA5F.png

**

```
#include <iostream> //library for input output stream
#include <fstream> //library for reading and writing files
#include <assert.h> //for the assert function
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;

//score variables
int s1 = 0,s2 = 0,s3 = 0,s4 = 0,s5 = 0;
//student answer variables
char q1,q2,q3,q4,q5;

//answer variables
char a1 = 'b';
char a2 = 'd';
char a3 = 'a';
char a4 = 'c';
char a5 = 'b';

//fstream variables 1 for each file
fstream file1,file2,file3;

char Continue;
do{
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t Gr 12 Computer Science File Handling C++ Quiz"<<endl;

    cout<<"\nOkay user, please enter in your first name: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;

    cout<<"\nHello "<<name<<", this Quiz has a total of 5 marks, each question is worth 1 marks. Good Luck!"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    file1.open("AnswerSheet.txt", ios::out);
        file1<<"-----"<<endl;
        file1<<"AnswerSheet"<<endl;
        file1<<"Q1: "<<a1<<endl;
        file1<<"Q2: "<<a2<<endl;
        file1<<"Q3: "<<a3<<endl;
        file1<<"Q4: "<<a4<<endl;
        file1<<"Q5: "<<a5<<endl;
        file1<<"-----"<<endl;
    file1.close();

    file2.open("Quiz.txt", ios::out);
        cout<<"\n-----"<<endl;
        cout<<"1: When working with multiple files (at the same time), the stream variables"<<endl;
        cout<<"\na. must all be of the same type, such as all ifstream, or all ofstream.";
        cout<<"\nb. must each be named independently, such as fin1, fin2, or fout1, fout2.";
        cout<<"\nc. must all be named the same, such as all fin and/or fout.";
        cout<<"\nd. are not needed since multiple files are present.";
        cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<endl;
        cin>>q1;
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        cout<<"-----"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n2: The required header file that allows classes of ofstream and ifstream to become available is"<<endl;
        cout<<"\na. iostream";
        cout<<"\nb. filestream";
        cout<<"\nc. assert.h";
        cout<<"\nd. fstream";
        cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<endl;
        cin>>q2;
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        cout<<"-----"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n3: When creating a new file, if a file of the same name already exists,"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nthe system will inform you that that file name is already in use.";
        cout<<"\na. true";
        cout<<"\nb. false";
        cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<endl;
        cin>>q3;
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        cout<<"-----"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n4: In the statement: obj2.open(\"myfile.dat\", ios::in); the ios::in is the"<<endl;
        cout<<"\na. stream variable name";
        cout<<"\nb. name of the file";
        cout<<"\nc. stream operation mode";
        cout<<"\nd. name of the buffer"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<endl;
        cin>>q4;
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        cout<<"-----"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n5: What is the purpose of this line of code? Be specific."<<endl;
        cout<<"\nfout.open(\"name.dat\",ios::app);";
        cout<<"\na. Open a brand new binary file.";
        cout<<"\nb. Append the file";
        cout<<"\nc. ios::app is a new file";
        cout<<"\nd. Delete the file";
        cout<<"\nANSWER: "<<endl;
        cin>>q5;
        cout<<"-----"<<endl;

        file2<<"-----"<<endl;
        file2<<name<<", Quiz answers"<<endl;
        file2<<"Q1: "<<q1<<endl;
        file2<<"Q2: "<<q2<<endl;
        file2<<"Q3: "<<q3<<endl;
        file2<<"Q4: "<<q4<<endl;
        file2<<"Q5: "<<q5<<endl;
        file2<<"-----"<<endl;

file2.close();

string read1,read2;

file1.open("AnswerSheet.txt", ios::in);
file2.open("Quiz.txt", ios::in);

    while(getline(file1,read1) && getline(file2,read2))
    {
            if(a1 == q1)
            s1++;
            if(a2 == q2)
            s2++;
            if(a3 == q3)
            s3++;
            if(a4 == q4)
            s4++;
            if(a5 == q5)
            s5++;

    file3.open("ScoreUser.txt", ios::out);

            int totalscore = (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5);

            file3<<"\n-----"<<endl;
            file3<<"Student name: "<<name<<", scores"<<endl;
            file3<<"Question 1 score: "<<s1<<endl;
            file3<<"Question 2 score: "<<s2<<endl;
            file3<<"Question 3 score: "<<s3<<endl;
            file3<<"Question 4 score: "<<s4<<endl;
            file3<<"Question 5 score: "<<s5<<endl;
            file3<<"total score: "<<totalscore<<"/5"<<endl;
            file3<<"-----"<<endl;

    file1.close();
    file2.close();
    file3.close();
    }

    file3.open("ScoreUser.txt", ios::in);
    string read3;
    while(getline(file3,read3))
    {
            cout<<read3<<endl;
    }
    file3.close();


    cout<<"\n Enter y to take quiz or enter n to terminate"<<endl;
    cin>>Continue;

    }while(Continue == 'y' || Continue == 'Y');

    file3.open("ScoreUser",ios::trunc);
    file3.close();

    if(Continue != 'y'|| Continue != 'Y')
    {
        cout<<"program terminated"<<endl;
    }
}
```

After running the code it keeps the same score as the previous user and then adds it onto the next user's score. I want it so that after every time the code loops again the variables will be reset or something like that where I wont have this scoring issue

[Desired Routput of User Scores][2]

This is the result after I run the code more than once, see how the scores double because it is saving the previous user file value or something like that  **

## Problem - https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2U4W.png Desired Output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcBv2.png

**

Comment: Why not reset your variables when you enter the `do` loop?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you for the response sir but, how would I do that if I may ask?

Comment: `s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = s5 = 0;` and the same for `qx` variables and reset answer `a1 = 'b'; , ...` I didn't pick thought the entire code, but it looks like one loop handles all questions, so you just need to reset at the top of the loop.. Also, you only need ONE `std::cout << ...` for any continual block of text, or one `file2 << ...` not one-per-line-of-output.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you so much I am truly grateful for your help.

Comment: Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resseting your variables is the solution to your problem. Look at the following line for example:

```
s1++;
```

Here you can see you are adding 1 to s1, which is ok, but the value of s1 matters at that point. During the first iteration, s1 = 0 (before the above line of code). But if the answer was correct, in the second iteration s1 = 1 (before the above line of code), and then the above line of code will set the value of s1 to 2.

So you can do either of the following:

1: Reset the variables:

```
s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0, s5 = 0; // Add this line of code at the end of your do-while loop
```

..as such:

```
    cout << "\n Enter y to take quiz or enter n to terminate" << endl;
    cin >> Continue;

    s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0, s5 = 0;
        
} while (Continue == 'y' || Continue == 'Y');
```

Or declare your variables inside the do-while loop as such:

```
//score variables
//int s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0, s5 = 0;
//student answer variables
char q1, q2, q3, q4, q5;

//answer variables
char a1 = 'b';
char a2 = 'd';
char a3 = 'a';
char a4 = 'c';
char a5 = 'b';

//fstream variables 1 for each file
fstream file1, file2, file3;

char Continue;
do {
    int s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0, s5 = 0; // Declare variables here

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Gr 12 Computer Science File Handling C++ Quiz" << endl;
```

Either of the above options will fix your issue.